# Access subclass variables from parent file

Tags: python, abc

I am looking for a way to access a subclasses variables from the parent class which is instantiated in a different file. For example

basefile.py:

```
class A(object): #gets subclassed
    var = 0 #place holder

    def printTheVar(self):
        print self.var


class B(object):
    def buildAndCallA(self):
        a = A()
        a.printTheVar()
```

implementationfile.py:

```
from basefile import *

class A(A):
    var = 10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b = B()
    b.buildAndCallA()
```

When I run:

```
$ python implementationfile.py
```

**I get 0. I want to get 10**

When both parent class and implementation class are in the same file, this is obviously not a problem but I have a project structure which requires they not be:

```
somedir/
| basefile.py
| implementations/
| -- implementationA.py
| -- implementationB.py
| -- implementationC.py
```

I think that the `abc` module might help but my experiments with that have proven fruitless so far.

Comment: When you do `a = A()` in `buildAndCallA`, you are creating an instance of the `A` class in `basefile.py`, not the one in `implementationfile.py`.  If you want `B` to use the `A` from the other file, you will have to import it --- but then you will have some other issues to think about, as this will be a circular import.  Why are you naming both classes `A` in the first place?

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve here?  It looks like you may want to be using instances and instance methods rather than subclasses and companion classes.

Comment: @BrenBarn yes that is exactly as I understand it and what I am probably looking for a clean way to do that circular import. I am naming both classes the same thing because I want to be able to instantiate an 'A' from either the basefile or the implementationfile without confusion. I suppose they could be named different things but I don't think that would solve any problems

Comment: If you want to avoid confusion, don't give two different classes the same name.  If you want to be able to instantiate either of two classes, you'll need to pass an argument as described the answer by James Holderness below.  If you write `A` in `buildAndCallA`, it will always refer to the A in the same file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@James's answer got me most of the ways there. Here is a more global way to do it using three files for clarity (which is really how the project is organized anyways)

script.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.argv[0] == 'useImplementation1'
        import implementations.implementation1 as implementation
    elif sys.argv[1] == 'useImplementation2':
        import implementations.implementation2 as implementation

    b = implementation.B(cls=implementation)
    b.buildAndCallA()
```

basefile.py (notice the `A = cls.A` this is the key):

```
class A(object):
    var = 0 #place holder

    def printTheVar(self):
        print self.var


class B(object):
    def __init__(self,cls):
        global A
        A = cls.A

    def buildAndCallA(self):
        a = A()
        a.printTheVar()
```

implementation1.py:

```
from basefile import *

class A(A):
    var = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest, if possible, you pass the class you want to use to the `buildAndCallA` method. So it should look something like this:

```
def buildAndCallA(self,cls):
    a = cls()
    a.printTheVar()
```

And then you can call it like this:

```
b.buildAndCallA(A)
```

Then it will use whatever version of the `A` class is in scope at the time it is called.

You could even set it up with a default parameter, so it will use the version of `A` in the base file by default, but you can still override it when necessary.

```
def buildAndCallA(self,cls=A):
    a = cls()
    a.printTheVar()
```

Then if you call `b.buildAndCallA()` with no parameter, it will construct an instance of the `A` class from the base file.